# How to call onclick twice in same element

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm trying to make it so when you click on this td, changeImage() function comes into place. Problem is, i dont know how to set it to default, when you click same td tag again - restoring it to orignal.

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td id="s1" class="kvadratek" onclick="changeImage();">?</td>
        <td id="s2" class="kvadratek slike">?</td>
        <td id="s3" class="kvadratek slike">?</td>
        <td id="s4" class="kvadratek slike">?</td>
    </tr>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage(){
        document.getElementById("s1").style.backgroundImage = "url('css/image1.jpg')";
        document.getElementById("s1").style.backgroundSize = "contain";
        document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = "";

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set a toggle

```
function changeImage(){
    var tag = event.target;  //or document.getElementById("s1");
    if(tag.style.backgroundImage !== "url('css/image1.jpg')") {
        tag.style.backgroundImage = "url('css/image1.jpg')";
        tag.style.backgroundSize = "contain";
        tag.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else {
     //set original settings here. 
    }

}
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki It could, but it's often best to change the original post as little as possible since that was not the point of the question

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeImage(){
    changed = (bool) document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("s1").style.backgroundImage = changed ? '' : "url('css/image1.jpg')";
    document.getElementById("s1").style.backgroundSize = changed ? '' :"contain";
    document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = changed ? '?' : '';
}
```